# React Router prefix

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a multilingual site in React and I'm using react router for my routing. Right now I have it setup where the prefix has to be present in order to transition to the route.

What I'm trying to do is the following: When I go to *localhost:3000* I want my app to transition to the home component. And when I go to 
*localhost:3000/jp* I still want to transition to the home component except now my language prefix would be *jp*.

I want English to be the default language and for other languages they have to be present in the prefix.
Right now it only transitions to the home component if I enter *localhost:3000/en*.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { Home } from '../containers/home';
import { About } from '../containers/about';
import { Contact } from '../containers/contact';


export default class Routes extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/:lang/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/:lang/contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="/:lang/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add all supported locales to your `:lang` param so it won't fail loading the end of the path

Comment: One question before posting a possible answer, are you using the `react-boilerplate` ? or `redux` ? how are you managing the multilanguage ?

Comment: Also, the default language must be a part of you `store` of the higher context component managing your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) at the end which will be matched when nothing else does and it will redirect to the `/en`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import { Home } from '../containers/home';
import { About } from '../containers/about';
import { Contact } from '../containers/contact';


export default class Routes extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/:lang/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/:lang/contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="/:lang/" component={Home} />
                <Redirect to="/en" />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/18rm8k82lj

---

**Updated answer (*due to comment*)**

The problem is that the `/:lang/` will match `/about` and the lang will be set to `about`.

A solution is to use the `render` prop of the route and decide what you want to do there

```
export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    const supportedLanguages = ["en", "jp", "de", "es"];
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:lang/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/:lang/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route
          path="/:lang/"
          render={props =>
            supportedLanguages.includes(props.match.params.lang) ? (
              <Home {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to={`/en/${props.match.params.lang}`} />
            )
          }
        />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/k2n9997345

Comment: But that would not give me the option of going to the other pages. It would just go to the home page. I want to be able to get to localhost:3000/about or localhost:3000/contact without having to put /en.

Comment: @Jir added an update to the answer that can handle that situation